# Seperate Android Gradle Jvm version for app and unit tests

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

Is it possible to set `jvmTarget = "1.8"` only for unit tests in gradle for an Android app? I was using:

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

But then I got crashes on older 4.4 devices...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that simply by setting `jvmTarget` for a certain Kotlin compilation task.

In an Android project, the unit tests are normally compiled by the tasks `compileDebugUnitTestKotlin`, `compileReleaseUnitTestKotlin` etc. You may find the complete list of Gradle tasks in the IDE's Gradle view or by running:

```
./gradlew tasks --all
```

Search for the names following the pattern `compile*Kotlin`.

Then just configure the single task that you need, for example:

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile)
    .matching { it.name == "compileDebugUnitTestKotlin" }
    .all { 
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but think I tried that, gradle told me there&#39;s no such task on the Project. Even junitPlatform configs (that I think are normally configured in the task) need a special plugin and to be provided in the `android { testOptions { } }` section. I&#39;m not sure how these plugins do it though, I think the problem starts because of all the variations and flavours possible in Android.

Comment: Ah sorry, I see. These tasks are created late during the configuration phase and are not yet available at the build script execution time.

Comment: @dave08 I've updated the answer. An alternative would be to configure that task in an `afterEvaluate { ... }` block just accessing it by name.

Comment: The tests seem to run (tried the way you mentioned in the edit), but Android Studio (3.2) seems to still think I'm using 1.6... could that be? And how can I check that it worked? On the test run command in the IDE output window, I don't see any mention of jvm-target, whereas one of my test dependencies requires 1.8.